# Phaser 3 piercing bullet hit multiple times

Tags: overlap, phaser-framework, collider

for a game I try to make bullets that pierce enemies, which itself is kinda easy thanks to the overlap() function.
My problem is that the bullets hit the enemies multiple times and kill them instantly in the end.

Is there a way to say "hit/collide only one time per enemy"?

My collision:

```
this.scene.physics.add.overlap(
     this.scene.enemyGroup, 
     this.scene.playerProjectiles_PierceEnemies, 
     function (enemy, projectile) {
          enemy.health -= projectile.dmg;
          if (enemy.health == 0) {
              enemy.destroy();
          }
     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a "is_live" attribute to the bullet and upon collision update the attribute to false, and then in your overlap() function only check live bullets.

Comment: I think tried similar things by setting my bullet's dmg (dmg is an attribute of the bullet) to 0 after it's first collision.
The problem was that the bullet couldn't hit any other mobs (actually hit with 0 dmg).

Comment: Then perhaps have an attribute that stores which mobs it has hit, and if the mob has already been hit, then no damage is done, else damage is done. Alternately, you could compute the amount of time that needs to pass for the bullet to no longer trigger the overlap function and then set the bullet to live again, or just after it hits the mob, relocate it to outside the mob.

Comment: Your idea of having an attribute that stores the mob worked.

I gave my projectile an attribute that stores the enemy object it hit (peformance-wise maybe a bad idea to store the whole object, I might change it later to IDs).
Also I had to reset this attribute (set to null) whenever the projectile get "destroyed", I think that's because of how I create my projectiles.
However this worked fine, except for one thing.

Comment: Whenever two or more enemies were near together or overlaping the projectiles attribute switched between them end instakilled them again. 
I fixed that by turning my projectile attribute into an array and add all newly hit enemies and asked if any elements are the currently hit one.

Now it works exactly as I wanted, Thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad to help!